# How do I get a list of functions defined in a DLL?

Tags: windows, winapi, dll

Assuming I have a list of DLL's an executable loads, How do I get a list of all the functions defined by those DLL's?

EDIT: preferably without the use of GUI's or huge programs like Visual Studio

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

You're not saying if you want to do this from code or you're just looking for a utility. For the latter, try dumpbin.exe from the Windows SDK, for the former check out the psapi and or toolhelp APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Dependency Walker can also be used which is a single executable.